# what is the format of word alignments in machine translation?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, language-translation, machine-translation

I am reading [this](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P05-1032) paper and having a difficulty understanding the way word alignments are represented. To be precise, right below section `4.1`, the authors say the format of the alignment is `(i,j)` where `i` ranges within the source sentence length and `j` ranges within the target sentence range. This means that each alignment is a pair of two numbers, which given that sentences are typically not longer than 40-100 words, values for `i`, and `j` can be stored using `short` type. So, I expect to see that the amount of space required to store these alignments be `2 x sizeof(short) x number of word alignments`. But if you go to the next page where, right above section `4.2`, they say the space is `sizeof(short) x number of word alignments`. WHY? Am I confusing stuff?

Comment: According to what you show in your question (haven't read the actual paper) it seems they're using the type Short to store the both values, assuming Short is 16-bit something like 8 bits for i and 8 bits for j. Also for values between 40-100 8 bits is more than enough to store those values.

Comment: right - makes sense. But I am not sure if I have a correct interpretation of the text they put in the paper. A bit doubtful about my understanding of it (and the way I pitched the question)...

Comment: After reading the 4.1 section you mention it does seem like my previous comment is correct however it appears they define the storage of alignments in 2-byte values and that the maximum length of a phrase worth storing is 10 and as such a 2-byte value is more than sufficient. You seem to indicate that they won't be longer than 40-100 words but they indicate in the paper that a drop off at a phrase of length 6 and that a length of 10 should cover a non-trivial portion of the corpus.